# Using Lisp to reprint a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a small and interesting problem,but I cannot come with a perfect solution,I would be grateful if you could help me or give me a hint on this.
The problem is :

given any list ,say like '(a b c),we will convert it to '[a b c]
or '(a (b c)) ,we will convert to '[A [B C]]

In other words,the function should do the same thing as PRINT in LISP,except we change the parentheses to square brackets.But methods like simply printing to a string then replace the parentheses to square brackets don't count.
Please give me some idea,thank you.

Comment: Smells like homework.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: thx,Robert
i got the code now 
(defun show-list (lst) 
  (cond
   ((and
    (atom lst)
    (not (null lst)))
    (format t "~A " lst))
   
   ((null lst)
    (format t "]" lst))
   
(t
    (format t "[")
    (show-list (car lst))
    (mapcar #'show-list (butlast (cdr lst))) 
    (format t "]"))

 ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
(defun bprint (object)
  (typecase object
    (cons
     (write-char #\[)
     (do ((list object (rest list)))
         ((endp list) (write-char #\]))
       (bprint (first list))
       (when (rest list)
         (write-char #\Space))))
    (t
     (prin1 object)))
  t)
```

That is: when encountering a list, print an opening bracket, print the contents recursively, adding a space after an object if necessary, then print a closing bracket. Print all non-list objects with prin1. prin1 is the "produce READable output" printer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great book: [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book).

You might want to start here if you're in a hurry:  [List Processing](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html) and [Format Recipes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html)